# Proof verification: if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable and $\lim_{x\to c\in(a,b)}f(x)$ exists, then $F=\int_a^x f$ is differentiable at $c$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification

The first fundamental theorem of calculus reads as follows:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is continuous over $[a,b]$ and differentiable over $(a,b)$. Moreover, for every $x\in(a,b)$, $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Slightly lesser known is the following local generalization of this important theorem. Here, "local" means that it gives information about $F$ at individual points.

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable over its domain and continuous at $c\in(a,b)$, then the function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable at $c$. Moreover, $F'(c)=f(c)$.

I've thought about this statement for a while now, and have concluded it can be further generalized to the following statement, which only assumes the existence of a limit at $c$:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable over its domain and $\lim_{x\to c\in(a,b)}f(x)=L$ for some $L\in\mathbb{R}$, then the function $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)dt$ is differentiable at $c$. Moreover, $F'(c)=L$.

Here's my argument:

Suppose $f$ is Riemann-integrable and $\lim_{x\to c\in(a,b)}f(x)=L$. Define $F$ as in the problem statement. For every $x\in[a,b]$ with $x\neq c$, we can write
$$\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=\frac{\int_a^x f(t)dt-\int_a^c f(t)dt}{x-c}=\frac{1}{x-c}\int_c^x f(t)\text{ }dt\tag{1}$$
Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$. Since $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$, there is a $\delta >0$ such that
$$|f(t)-L|<\varepsilon\text{ for every }t\in[a,b]\text{ with }0<|t-c|<\delta$$
that is,
$$L-\varepsilon<f(t)<L+\varepsilon\text{ for every }t\in[a,b]\text{ with }t\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$$
Fix a $d>0$ satisfying $d<\min\{c-a,b-c,\delta\}$. Then the interval $(c-d,c+d)$ is a subset of $[a,b]$ and $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, so
$$L-\varepsilon<f(t)<L+\varepsilon\text{ for every }t\in (c-d,c+d)\tag{2}$$
Now, given any $x\in(c-d,c+d)$ with $x\neq c$, either $x<c$ or $x>c$. If $x<c$, then it follows from $(2)$ and $[x,c]\subset (c-d,c+d)$ that
$$\int_x^c (L-\varepsilon)\text{ }dt<\int_x^c f(t)\text{ }dt<\int_x^c (L+\varepsilon)\text{ }dt$$
$$\implies (L-\varepsilon)(c-x)<-\int_c^x f(t)\text{ }dt<(L+\varepsilon)(c-x)$$
$$\implies L-\varepsilon<-\frac{1}{c-x}\int_c^x f(t)\text{ }dt<L+\varepsilon\text{ (this follows from }c-x>0\text{)}$$
$$\implies L-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{x-c}\int_c^x f(t)\text{ }dt<L+\varepsilon$$
which, from $(1)$, implies
$$L-\varepsilon<\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}<L+\varepsilon$$
$$\implies \left|\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-L\right|<\varepsilon$$
The same conclusion can be reached if $x>c$, so for every $x\in(c-d,c+d)$ with $x\neq c$,
$$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-L\right|<\varepsilon$$
$\varepsilon>0$ was fixed arbitrarily, so the preceding argument can be applied to every positive real number. Thus, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $d>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}-L\right|<\varepsilon\text{ for every }x\in[a,b]\text{ with }0<|x-c|<d$$
which, from the definition of a limit, implies that $\lim_{x\to c}\frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c}=L$ and consequently that $F'(c)$ exists and equals $L$. $\blacksquare$

I appreciate any and all feedback.

Comment: I didn't read your argument since it sounded like you are missing a key piece of information: a function is Riemann integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities has (Lebesgue) measure zero. So, $L = f(c)$ for almost every $c$ (so, you are not winning anything relative to the continuity proof).

Comment: The third version follows directly from the second one. Indeed, consider $$g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x),& x\neq c,\\ L,& x=c.\end{cases}$$ Then $g$ is continuous at $x=c$ and the integral doesn't care about a single point, so $F(x)=\int_a^x g(t) dt$ is differentiable by the second version and $F'(c)=g(c)=L$.

Comment: Your proof is correct, although you mix up $t$ and $x$ sometime, as in "$|f(t)-L|<\varepsilon\text{ for every }x\in[a,b]\text{ with }0<|x-c|<\delta$ for every $x$ etc.". :-)

Comment: @OlivierRoche I just noticed that. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 5):

Allow me to shorten your proof for you. Define

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  f(x) & x \neq c \\
  L & x = c \end{cases}$$

Then $g : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, as it differs from the Riemann integrable function $f$ in at most 1 place. Moreover, we see that for all $x \in [a, b]$, we have $F(x) = \int\limits_a^x f(t) dt = \int\limits_a^x g(t) dt$, since $f$ and $g$ differ at at most 1 point. Finally, $g$ is continuous at $c$. Therefore, by your local lemma, we have $F'(c) = g(c) = L$.

Comment: I love this proof!

Comment: $g$ is the bulldozer! I laughed with satisfaction when I saw your proof :'-)

Comment: @OlivierRoche It seems someone came up with exactly the same proof in the comments at exactly the same time as I did, which is quite amusing indeed.